# in_array() not working

Tags: php, html

My code:

```
<?php

$pass = "12345";

//checkPass($pass, $user, $length);
$file = file_get_contents("common.txt");
$array = explode("\n", $file);
if(in_array($pass, $array) == true) {
 echo "it's in the array";
}
?>
```

first few lines of the array (i used print_r($array)...):

```
Array ( [0] => 12345 [1] => abc123 [2] => password [3] => computer [4] => 123456 
[5] => tigger [6] => 1234 [7] => a1b2c3 [8] => qwerty [9] => 123 [10] => xxx 
[11] => money [12] => test [13] => carmen [14] => mickey [15] => secret 
[16] => summer [17] => internet [18] => service [19] => canada [20] => hello 
[21] => ranger [22] => shadow [23] => baseball [24] => donald [25] => harley 
[26] => hockey [27] => letmein [28] => maggie [29] => mike [30] => mustang 
[31] => snoopy
```

Comment: Can you post where you set $pass equal to its value at the time?

Comment: It's at the top of the file, right after the opening PHP tag. I tried editing it all in above but something's not working right.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If your file uses Windows linebreaks (lines end in `\r\n`), you'll get an invisible `\r` character at the end of each of your strings. Test for it by running strlen() on one of them:

```
echo $array[0] . ': ' . strlen($array[0]) . ' chars';
```

If you get something like

```
12345: 6 chars
```

You know that's the problem! You can get rid of these characters after exploding the array using [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) with [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim):

```
$array = array_map('trim', $array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I came up with that worked:

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents("common.txt"); 

$array = explode("\n", $file); 

$pass = "snoopy";

if(in_array($pass, $array) == true) {     
    echo "it's in the array";     
}else {    
    echo "it's not";    
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you may want to use `trim` on that too.  could be invisible chars you are not seeing by eye.

Answer (score 1):

is $pass a value of 0 - 31?